# Browser protocol handler options for ios

Tags: ios, browser

By browser protocol handler I mean spotifiy:// and coda://.

What options exist for iOS safari. Could I specify a BPH for dropbox or evernote and the browser would know to prompt "open item in evernote" for example?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-[UIApplication openURL:]` to open an arbitrary URL. If another app has registered for the protocol scheme, they will then handle the URL. Similarly there's `-[UIApplication canOpenURL:]` to find out if a URL scheme can be handled before you attempt to invoke it. Note however, the OS does not prompt the user when you open a URL, it simply launches the app that's currently registered for that URL scheme and gives them the URL. If you want to prompt the user before this happens, you should do so yourself.

Comment: And i can use this in a web app? (i'm not on about native apps)

Comment: In a web app you can just redirect the `window.location.href` to the URL of your choice. I don't know if any way to test if a scheme is supported before trying to open it.